# Equivalence between a SDE and an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $X$ be a continuous semimartingale. We look at the following SDE

$$dY(t)=Y(t)dX(t)$$

with $Y(0)=1$ and $Y>0$.

The above notation means $Y(t) = 1 + \int_0^t Y(s) \, dX(s)$, it's just a notation.

Wikipedia says that if $X$ is differentiable (meaning it sample paths are differentiable), the equation is equivalent to the ODE

$$Y'(t)=Y(t)X'(t)$$

Is there a way to see this without solving the SDE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X(t)$ has differentiable sample paths, there is a process $\xi_t$ such that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds path-wise, i.e.

$$ \int_0^t dX_s = X_t-X_0 = \int_0^t \xi_s ds $$

which implies the equivalence of the measures $dX_t$ and $\xi_t dt$ (show it for simple processes first, then use continuity of the integral). Using this fact, we obtain

$$ Y_t-Y_0 = \int_0^t dY_s =  \int_0^t Y_s dX_s = \int_0^t Y_s \xi_s ds$$

which implies that $Y_t$ itself is differentiable and has derivative $Y_t \xi_t$.
If we denote $X'_t=\xi_t$, we get the desired result.